# my eclipse ide can't compile my android program

Tags: java, android, eclipse

am not new to java programming. I recently downloaded the android SDK to begin practice android programming. 
my eclipse Ide hasn't really been friendly with me because, at first it refused to install the adt plugin I donwloaded. till I installed it from google. and now it find it difficult to run even the helloworld program. it gives me several errors. 
something about */user/***/res/value/*.xml not found or dark theme something not found, appcompat.v7 no resoirse found .
and also do I really to install all the items in the android SDK before I can compile anything. because the file size of my android-SDK-windows file is way over 10gb. and it looks odd plus my data bundle has been exhausted.

thanks..

Comment: Be Cool and try this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/797553/Setting-Up-Your-Android-Development-Environment

Comment: You might want to try Google's Android Studio instead of Eclipse.

Comment: There may be some property linking missed while using latest sdk. do right click on your project-> properties-> Java Build Path -> check for the libraries tab whether all jars are ok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Welcome to android Platform

**`Question1`:** "my eclipse Ide hasn't really been friendly with me"

Practice makes you perfect. Eclipse is a good tool once you get to know it

**`Question2`:** "Do I really to install all the items in the android SDK before I can compile anything"

No, you just need any once of the API ex: API-14 install it

**`Question3`:** "It find it difficult to run even the helloworld program"

Download a sample project online import into your eclipse and run it if you are new to android

### Happy Coding !!

Comment: Thanks, am actually new to android buh I don't think its the code that gives me problem. because all I ve tried to do was create a simple hello-world display(I read about it). 
for some reason I think my old eclipse is just not seeing the updates I installed in my sdk manager. 
so may be I would try the android studio or download eclipse with adt plugin from google and try again.

Once I see it can build, then I can start practicing programming for android.

Comment: @ James Anyanwu .... If the answer helped mark it as accepted by checking the Green Arrow next to my answer or up-vote it ... so it helps someone looking for similar question !

Answer (score 0):

when using eclipse for android development it will always gives you errors its a nightmare that ull get used to. first of all make sure that the theme is fit for the sdk version that you mentioned in the manifest and two make sure that you have downloaded all the required items in the SDK. and try and refresh the project few times or even restart eclipse.